# Size LinearLayout to the Width of ImageView

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-widget

In my Fragment XML i have an imageview which functions as a background. In that same layout i got a LinearLayout which holds some buttons that should be viewed horizontally on the view and have the same width as the background. My code sizes it to the width of the screen because of wrap_content. How can I size it to the imageview?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="45sp" >

<ImageView 
        android:src="@drawable/background_detail_view"
        android:id="@+id/detailview_background"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/detailview_background_description" />

<!-- more widgets -->

<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/detail_button_container"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/titel" >

        <Button 
        android:id="@+id/detail1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:text="1"/>

<Button 
        android:id="@+id/detail2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:text="2"/>

        <Button 
        android:id="@+id/detail3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:text="3"/>

<!-- more buttons -->

</LinearLayout>
```

I tried getting the width programatically and assigning that tot new layoutparams but that returns 0 because the view isnt rendered yet.

Answer (score 1):

In your LinearLayout, set the `android:background="@drawable/background_detail_view"` parameter, so that your LinearLayout will has this background, instead of using an ImageView.

Comment: jeah.. good thinking. Need to change the layout because a lot was defined "below the ImageView" and have to reorganise. Ill keep you updated